From degree theory on sub-manifolds to abstract smooth manifolds
I am studying the degree theory on smooth manifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I would like to see how bridge this theory in a more general setting.
In a previous post, a comment proposed 2 ways to define the degree on an abstract smooth manifold :
1- the first was to work directly on such manifolds which is, after studying it the more natural way in fact
2- the second was to extend it by using Whitney embedding theorem
This post is about the second way that I did not manage to prove.
Here is my attempt : My idea was to consider a smooth map $f:M\to N$ where $M$ and $N$ are abstract smooth manifolds of dimension $m$ and $n$ without boundary with $M$ compact and $N$ connected. By Whitney theorem, there exists smooth immersions $F : M\to\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ and $\tilde{F} : N\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $F(M)$ and $\tilde{F}$ are sub-manifolds.
From this, my idea was to consider the map $g : F(M)\to\tilde{F}(N)$ defined by $g(F(x))=\tilde{F}(f(x))$ and define the degree of $f$ as being the degree of $g$.
For this I need to check that $g$ is a smooth map : I did not manage to check it using the fact that  $g=\tilde{F}\circ f\circ F^{-1}$
I need to check that if $y\in N$ is a regular value of $f$, then $\tilde{F}(y)$ is a regular value of $g$ but here also, I did not manage to check this.
Hence, I am wondering if the idea I had is wrong and if yes what can I do to correct this please
Thank you a lot !

Do you have additional hypotheses on $M$ and $N,$ for example compactness?

@Lieven Thank you for the comment ! Indeed I have compactness on $M$ and connectedness on $N$, sorry I forgot to mention that

Composition of smooth maps 8s smooth.

@MoisheKohan My doubt was on the smoothness of $F^{-1}$ but I see that Lieven has answered, I will look to that !

I think you are misunderstanding what a smooth embedding into $\mathbb R^k$  is: It is a diffeomorphism from an abstract manifold to a submanifold of $\mathbb R^k$. A diffeomorphism by definition has smooth inverse. There is nothing to be proven there. (Some suboptimal sources define embeddings differently but then they prove that every embedding is a diffeomorphism to its image.)

@MoisheKohan You are totally right I did see that it is an homeomorphism to its image but since in general smooth and homeomorphism does not imply diffeomorphism I did not even try to prove that, which I should do now. Thank you !

Let $y$ be a regular value of $f$ and let $x$ be any point in its inverse image. We must prove that $F(x)$ is a regular point of $g.$
We know that $x$ is a regular point of $f,$ i.e., $df(x)$ is an injective linear map from $T_xM$ into $T_yN.$  Choose a coordinate system on a neighbourhood of $x$ in $M.$
$F$ being an immersion, $dF(x)$ is an injective linear map from $T_xM$ into $T_{F(x)}\mathbb R^{2m}$ represented by a $2m\times m$ matrix of rank $m.$ Without loss of generality (rotate $\mathbb R^{2m}$ if necessary) suppose that the top $m\times m$ submatrix is already invertible, i.e., a small neighbourhood of $x$ is actually embedded in $\mathbb R^m.$ By the inverse function theorm $F^{-1}$ (restricted to the first $m$ coordinates) is smooth in a small neighbourhood of $F(x).$ This proves that $g$ is smooth. $F^{-1}$ is by definition invertible in the same small neighbourhood so its differential at $F(x)$ is an injective linear mapping from $T_{F(x)}F(M)$ into $T_xM.$
To establish that $\tilde F(y)$ is a regular value of $g$ observe that any of its inverse images under $g$ are of the form $F(x)$ with $x$ in the inverse image of $y$ under $f.$ Then $\tilde F(y)=g(F(x))$ and $dg(F(x))=d(\tilde F\circ f\circ F^{-1})(F(x))$ which is the composition of three injective linear maps by virtue of the chain rule, and therefore injective.

Thank you a lot for your answer ! I have two questions : How the fact that $F^{-1}$  restricted to the first $ m$ coordinates is smooth implies that $g $ is smooth since g is the composition of $F^{-1}$ and not its restriction to the first $m$ coordinates ? Also for proving that $\tilde{F}(y)$ is a regular value of $g$ I do not understand why the argument involves injectivity of the differential ?

For the second question I ask, I have just that $dg_{F(x)}=d\tilde{F}{y}\circ df{x}$ with $df_{x}$ surjective and  $d\tilde{F}_{y}$ injective since it is an immersion no ?
